# SVN Mirror on Raspberry PI

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a SVN mirror on a Raspberry PI.  I've attached an external hard drive to the Pi and every time I try to dump in our SVN data I get this message
revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output
I can make the repository on the PI itself and it works fine but for some reason every time I get the above error when I try to use an external device like a external hard drive or thumb drive.
I'm running Raspbian on the PI

Answer (score 0):

`revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255)`

There is a [`pre-revprop-change`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) hook script configured on the repository. It's not clear what you mean by `I try to use an external device like a external hard drive or thumb drive.` but I guess that you are running `svnsync` or `svnrdump load` tools over HTTP(S) or svn://. These tools trigger the hook script as regular svn clients do.

Therefore, you have to check what this hook script does and modify it.